# Font in UITableViewCell rendered poorly ios7 non retina

Tags: ios, uitableview, fonts

Weird behaviour: I have a custom cell with two UILabel.
When I use the cell in my table I do standard things:

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    cell.labelVoce.text   = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                           [[avvDB sharedDB] formatDate:[elemento objectForKey:@"start"] fromFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" toFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"]];
    cell.labelVoce.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;

    return cell;

}
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
cell.selectionStyle             = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

[cell.layer setRasterizationScale:[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]];

cell.backgroundColor            = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.imageView.backgroundColor  = [UIColor clearColor];
}
```

But for some reason the fonts in the label at even index (2,4,6) are rendered poorly as in figure.
[image]

Does anyone knows why?

Comment: In your code cell labels have date strings. Can you show the code for displaying the cells shown in the figure?

Comment: I think the problem is in the heightForRow method I wrote which change the height based on the cell content. If I put a fixed height everything is fine...

Comment: Why are you calling setRasterizationScale:?

Comment: Because somebody suggested it here ...